# Android MapView Overlay Image not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm trying to write a simple MapView using Google Maps API v1 (Targeting Gingerbread devices)

Just tried following the example [hello-mapview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview) and it all works apart from the image does not get displayed on the map.

There is an overlay, as the touch even works and displays the text, how ever no image appears with it.

Can anyone spot what I have missed?

MyMapView.java

```
public class MyMapView extends MapActivity {

private MapView mapView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    NewOverlay itemizedoverlay = new NewOverlay(drawable, this);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

NewOverlay.java

```
public class NewOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public NewOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public void removeOverlays(){
    mOverlays.clear();
    populate();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you should probably stop doing v1 example and do v2 since v1 is no longer supported

Comment: I'm targeting devices with API level 10 (Gingerbread), as I mentioned in my OP. v2 Uses fragments and they came in at API 11 so I cannot use it.

Comment: you sure can, its called the support library

Comment: Maybe you should explain yourself a little more, then your comments might actually be useful. Or answer the question at hand.

Comment: it would also be useful if you google android support library or better yet look on the developer website. here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html and here http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html